# Effect for logo automatic resize on the menu

Tags: wordpress, css

How can I achieve the logo resize and overlapping on the menu upon scrolling up/down ? Any wordpress plugin or code that can achieve this ?

Example of the effect that I want for the logo resize & overlapping is 
1) http://vespaadventures.com/
2) https://www.coupondunia.in/

Thanks and appreciate all the help and advice.

Comment: You need to use javascript. I don't think there will be a plugin that does this for you as it will usually be too different from logo to logo. In javascript you will need to use an event listener to capture scrolling and then add/remove a class on the element or parent element you are changing depending on the scroll position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: you need a pretty simple JQ to achieve that. but you should try it yourself and post here the code. this is not a code making site, nor a ' recommend a plugin ` one. see here how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var getNav = $("nav.navbar");
if( getNav.hasClass("navbar-sticky")){
  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop >100){
      $(".navbar-sticky").addClass("navbar-fixed");
    }else {
      $(".navbar-sticky").removeClass("navbar-fixed");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 800px;
}
.navbar-sticky{
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
.navbar-sticky{display:block !important;}
.navbar-fixed{
  position:fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-fixed .navbar-brand img{
  height: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky bootsnav" >

        <div class="container">         

            <!-- Start Header Navigation -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#brand"><img src="http://vespaadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/logo-website-va-011.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Header Navigation -->

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active scroll"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>   
    </nav>
```